# C# Deserializing List<BsonDocument> to List<ClassName> while ignoring bad data

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to deserialize `List<BsonDocument>` to `List<ClassName>`, but want to ignore the ones that fails to to deserialize.

For example:

```
    List<BsonDocument> bsonList = new List<BsonDocument> 
    {
        { 
            "name": "some string"
            "timestamp": "2023-05-05"
        },
        { 
            "name": "some string"
            "timestamp": "this object should be ignored"
        },
    }
```

to a list will become something like:

```
    List<Person> objectList= new List<Person> 
    {
        { 
            Name = "some string",
            Timestamp = "2023-05-05"
        }
    }
```

One approach I came up with is something like:

```
    var objectList = new List<Person>();
    foreach (var bson in bsonList)
    {
        try
        {
            objectList.Add(Bson.Deserialize<Person>(bson));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This bson element was ignored");
        }
    }
```

Is there any different way to do this or is this the only approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 global ways to think:

1. Configure `BsonIgnoreExtraElementsAttribute` (class level) that allows ignoring fields that don't match with the class structure.

   ```
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    private class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
    }

    var json = "{ _id : 1, X : 2, Y : 3, Z : 4 }";
    var entity = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entity>(json);
    Assert.IsType<Entity>(entity);
    Assert.Equal(1, entity.Id);
    Assert.Equal(2, entity.X);
   ```

Same approach without explicit attribute on Entity:

```
    private class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
    }  

    var json = "{ _id : 1, X : 2, Y : 3, Z : 4 }";
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Entity>(m =>
    {
        m.AutoMap();
        m.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
    });
    var entity = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entity>(json);
    Assert.IsType<Entity>(entity);
    Assert.Equal(1, entity.Id);
    Assert.Equal(2, entity.X);
```

A similar option with `BsonExtraElementsAttribute` (field level) that places unrecognized options into particular common field.

```
    private class Entity
    {
        public int Id;
        public int A;
        [BsonExtraElements]
        public IDictionary<string, object> X; // might be BsonDocument as well
    }

    var json = "{ _id : 1, A : 2, B : 3 }";
    var entity = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entity>(json);
    Assert.IsType<Entity>(entity);
    Assert.Equal(1, entity.Id);
    Assert.Equal(2, entity.A);
    Assert.Equal(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "B", 3 } }, entity.X);
```

Same approach without explicit attribute on Entity:

```
    private class Entity
    {
        public int Id;
        public int A;
        public IDictionary<string, object> X; // might be BsonDocument as well
    }

    var json = "{ _id : 1, A : 2, B : 3 }";
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Entity>(m =>
    {
        m.AutoMap();
        m.SetExtraElementsMember(m.GetMemberMap(m1 => m1.X));
    });
    var entity = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entity>(json);
    Assert.IsType<Entity>(entity);
    Assert.Equal(1, entity.Id);
    Assert.Equal(2, entity.A);
    Assert.Equal(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "B", 3 } }, entity.X);
```

2. Other options more complicated and require creating custom serializer for your type and define any behavior you want, something close too:

   ```
    public class EntitySerializer : ClassSerializerBase<Entity>
    {
        protected override Entity DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            var reader = context.Reader;

            var result = new Entity();

            reader.ReadStartDocument();

            while (reader.ReadBsonType() != BsonType.EndOfDocument)
            {
                var key = reader.ReadName();
                // check whether "result" contains requited keys and do appropriate steps
                // use reflection in common case
                switch (key)
                {
                    case "_id": result.Id = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(reader); break;
                    case "X": result.X = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(reader); break;
                    default: reader.SkipValue(); break;
                }
            }

            reader.ReadEndDocument();

            return result;
        }

        protected override void SerializeValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Entity value)
        {
            var writer = context.Writer;

            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            // use reflection in common scenario
            writer.WriteName("_id");
            writer.WriteInt32(value.Id);

            writer.WriteName("X");
            writer.WriteInt32(value.X);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    var json = "{ _id : 1, X : 2, Y : 3 }";
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer<Entity>(new EntitySerializer());
    var entity = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entity>(json);
    Assert.IsType<Entity>(entity);
    Assert.Equal(1, entity.Id);
    Assert.Equal(2, entity.X);

    var serialized = entity.ToJson();
    Assert.Equal("{ \"_id\" : 1, \"X\" : 2 }", serialized);

    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
    }
   ```