# Ignore property only when serialized with bson

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, bson

I need to configure the serializer so that during serialization the property does not fall into Bson Document, but during deserialization it does. When using the Bson Ignore attribute, serialization and deserialization don't work (which is logical), but I need a slightly different logic

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The easiest way is to handle this on your side, ie just do not send the data you don't want to see in the db, alternative will be creating a custom serializer - something close to #2 in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76284473/9492730 where you can add any custom logic you need

Comment: I'm having a problem. I have an IMongoCollection<MyClass> and I make my own serializer for the MyClass class, and when I try to register it, an Exception is thrown that the serializer is already registered for MyClass, although I don't register it anywhere (I assume that Mongo registers the base serializer itself)

Comment: RegisterSerializer should be called before any mongo operation

Comment: Could you show example of the result you need?

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following solution:
I decided to use BsonIgnoreIfNullAttribute for the properties I needed, created my own SourceIsIgnoredAttribute attribute and process it in the extension for the automapper.

```
public static class UnmapIgnoredMembersExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unmaps the ignored members with attribute - <see cref="SourceIsIgnoredAttribute"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TDestination">The type of the destination.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="mappingExpression">The mapping expression.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> UnmapIgnoredMembers<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mappingExpression)
    {
        var targetProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Public
            | BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.NonPublic
            ).Where(property => Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(SourceIsIgnoredAttribute)))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var property in targetProperties)
        {
            mappingExpression
                .ForMember(property.Name, q => q.Ignore());
        }

        return mappingExpression;
    }
}
```

As a result, unnecessary data doesn't get into db, and I can use lookup and other functions I need without any problems.